# Is it possible to add a class when popup is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, addclass

Is it possible to add a class when a popup is open using `window.open` with javascript or jquery?

Comment: you mean add a class in the popup'd window?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can access the opened window's properties.

```
var newWind = window.open('http://<url_here>', 'childWindow')

$j(newWind.document).find('html').addClass('opened-as-popup')
```

Comment: Works at least in FF4, with FireBug.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
var WindowObject = window.open('');
WindowObject.document.write('<body class="newClass">');
```

Comment: make this a comment instead of answer